# force connect to work

Tags: performance, unix, networking, connect, telnet

I run the following line in bash, on a VM running red hat 5:

```
    for i in {1..100000};
        do telnet 10.10.10.105 41941;
    done
```

At some point, telnet connects to the port even though there is no one listening on it. It seems o be connecting to its self?
The same issue appears when i start the client side of an application, **without** starting the server - the client successfully connects to the ip:port. The client looks something like this:

```
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(port));
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(hostname);

    some_while_loop
    {
        status = ::connect(sock, (sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
        if (status == -1)
        {
            shutdown(sock, 2);
            close(sock);
            return false;
        }
   }
```

I found this article: http://web.deu.edu.tr/doc/soket/ which states in 6.2 that the connection will succeed if you to the same machine you're running on. My question is, why is this happening? Is it a hardware issue or is it a fail-safe red-hat kernel is using, or maby it's because of the port i'm using (for 1025 for example, i don't have this issue)... ?

Answer (score 0):

It is correlated to the port. When initiiating a TCP connection, for the client, a random unused port in the upper range of the ports (32786+) is picked. Then the usual [TCP handshake](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#section-3.4) is done, only with a special case called simultanous initiiation. Here it is assumed that both sides of the connection want to establish a connection at  the same time, see below for a figure from the RFC.

You can enforce that behaviour using ncat:

```
ncat -p 50000 127.0.0.1 50000
```

This will make ncat connect to `127.0.0.1:50000`, while using the source port `50000`. You get a valid connection immediately, without having to listen for incoming connections beforehand.

---

Despite what commenters said, the case happening here is called **simultanous initiiation** and is well specified in [RFC 793, Section 3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#section-3.4), where it says:

> Simultaneous initiation is only slightly more complex, as is shown in   figure 8.  Each TCP cycles from CLOSED to SYN-SENT to
> SYN-RECEIVED to   ESTABLISHED.
>
> ```
>       TCP A                                            TCP B
>
>   1.  CLOSED                                           CLOSED
>
>   2.  SYN-SENT     --> <SEQ=100><CTL=SYN>              ...
>
>   3.  SYN-RECEIVED <-- <SEQ=300><CTL=SYN>              <-- SYN-SENT
>
>   4.               ... <SEQ=100><CTL=SYN>              --> SYN-RECEIVED
>
>   5.  SYN-RECEIVED --> <SEQ=100><ACK=301><CTL=SYN,ACK> ...
>
>   6.  ESTABLISHED  <-- <SEQ=300><ACK=101><CTL=SYN,ACK> <-- SYN-RECEIVED
>
>   7.               ... <SEQ=101><ACK=301><CTL=ACK>     --> ESTABLISHED
>
>                 Simultaneous Connection Synchronization
>
>                                Figure 8.
> ```

I also corrected the first paragraph to be more clear and precise.

Comment: Well, the reply to a SYN isn't an ACK, it is a SYN+ACK, which in turn has to be ACK'd before the connection is complete. I think the underlying mechanism here is somewhat different.

Comment: @EJP please see edited answer and reconsider downvote/deletevote!

Comment: @JonasWielicki, simultaneous initiation indeed seems to be the case, because on connection, said address and port aren't actually blocked, so connect() sees them as viable options to link the socket to. As a work around to this i found that you can `getsockname(sock, &sock_addr, &addr_size)` to check the ports if they are the same, and consequently close the connection. Also using setsockopt to set the above mentioned socket to reuse the address (SO_REUSEADDR), will solve any problems if the server is trying to use the same addres and port. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Exactly. If the ports _were_ blocked, they could not be used to connect initially. It seems a bit paradox at first though.